# Number of processors for a multi threading program

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, processor

We know that a processor can process only one thread at a time. So when we say multitasking on a single processor, means the processor switches between the threads/ processes and gives the end-user a feeling of multitasking. Related to it, I've some questions to better understand the concept of multi-threading -

- I think, totally it will take the same amount of time to execute all
  the processes in switching manner and executing them one by one, am I
  right?
- If yes, is there any benefit of dividing a task in multiple
  threads?
- What does it mean, when we say quad-core, octa-core processor? Does it mean a system has 4, 8 processors respectively and it can process 4/ 8 threads at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, it will take the same amount of time. In fact, it will take a bit longer, because the switching takes time.
- Dividing a task into multiple threads lets you use multiple processors.

  Also, the CPU isn't always the slowest thing. Imagine you have a chat server - you could use one thread for each client, and each thread would spend most of its time doing nothing (waiting for the user to type a message).
- A quad-core processor has 4 cores. An octa-core processor has 8 cores. Cores are pretty much separate processors, but on the same chip instead of separate chips.

Answer (score 0):

1 Imagine your task is to read several files. If you run several reading threads it may significantly improve performance

2 Imagine your task is to calculate a sum of a large array of numbers, if you run 2 threads on 2 parts of the array in parallel, the speed will increase by 2

Comment: Or significantly reduce it, if the head on your hard disc needs to keep moving back and forth between files. Depending on your technology.